# How to remove Sn from Sn60Cu40 alloy?

Tags: metal, metallurgy

I have practical question.

How can I chemically remove $\ce{Sn}$ from $\ce{Sn60Cu40}$ alloy?

I want to get something like copper sponge this way.

Something like nanoporous gold produced from $\ce{Au50Ag50}$ for heat exchanger, but cheaper.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! I have edited your question to make it look better for our site. First, I removed the quotation marks from your title - they are unnecessary. Second, I used our MathJax plugin to make your chemical formula look like a chemical formula. You can learn to do this for yourself. Start by checking out the [faq].

Comment: @Kamil see http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation specifically

Answer (score 5):

You can remove tin from bronze (copper-tin alloys) and leave behind the copper. However, doing so may not leave you with copper in an easy to use form.

Tin is a [less reactive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_series) metal than copper. Tin reacts with all acids, like $\ce{HCl}$, while copper only reacts with oxidizing acids, like $\ce{HNO3}$.

$$\ce{Sn(s) +2H+(aq) -> Sn^{2+}(aq) + H2 (g)^ }$$
$$\ce{Cu(s) + 2H+ (aq) -> No \ Reaction}$$
$$\ce{Cu(s) + 4H+(aq) + 2NO3- (aq) -> Cu^{2+} (aq) + 2H2O (l) + 2NO2 (g) ^}$$

Soaking your bronze in acid (even vinegar might work) will eventually dissolve the tin away from the copper. Heating, or using a stronger acid like the $\ce{HCl}$ in muriatic acid, will likely increase the rate. However, since the composition of the alloy is uniform throughout, the copper will likely come out of solution as a fine powder.

Comment: Well... Powder will not satisfy me. Please take a look at my updated question.

Comment: It is possible you would get the sponge this way. It might still be worth a try.

Comment: I think, that Sn/Cu ratio is not 50/50 and it may not work, but I have to try :)

Comment: Selective corrosion would definitely produce a copper sponge but I don't what chemicals selective removes tin in a tin/copper alloy.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.tuke.sk%2Fdata%2Fams_online%2F2004%2Fnumber4%2Fmag09%2Fmag09.pdf&ei=LeXiVK3mLoigNrCsg7gI&usg=AFQjCNGTjKIuTiRAh3LXqbx4CRpPQbWMsQ&sig2=9bY2yapC1xJ9bD8QA5zwbg&bvm=bv.85970519,d.eXY

Answer (score 0):

Well You need some kind of crystal structure even for sponge. Tin and copper forms an alloy and they have formed crystal structure together. So solving bronze in acid will destroy that structure, witch hold the peace as whole. Sponge can be formed from sintered peace if it is formed from zinc and copper powder. Then solving zinc whit acid will not destroy coppers crystal structure.